# Change the appearance of a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, windows, swing, jinternalframe

I have a JInternalFrame which is behaving in quite an odd way. I am currently developing my application on a Windows 8 machine and have set the application to run with native looks, this means all my JFrames and JDialogs look like native Windows 8 windows. The JInternalFrame is different, for some reason it seems to of inherited the Windows 7 aero look and feel!

Here is a screenshot:
[image: JInternalFrame look and feel error]

You will also notice the close button has been cut off slightly.
The code I am using to create the JInternalFrame is as follows:

```
editor = new BubbleEditor(app); // An extended JInternalFrame
editor.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
app.add(editor); // app is a JFrame that contains a JDesktopPane
editor.setSize(200, 100);
editor.setLocation(100, 100);
editor.setVisible(false);
try {
editor.setSelected(true);
} catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
```

I get exactly the same problem when I try a blank JInternalFrame in a fresh project. I just want to know if there is a way to get the actual native appearance of the OS and apply it to a JInternalFrame.

Comment: You should probably submit this as a bug at http://bugs.sun.com .  Out of curiosity, does the problem occur if you remove/comment out the editor.putClientProperty line?

Comment: I will do that then, I just thought I might be missing something. I'm going to try it on some different os's too. I do still get the problem without the editor.puClientProperty line, it is meant to style it like a utility toolbox but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Don't forget to `pack()` each `JInternalFrame`.